# Auto modify the model

Tags: sapui5

I have a json model with many values.
I map the values in a form (into  input fields). then I edit the values.
I want auto modify the model when I press a confirm button (withour change the model field to field)
Can I do it??

Comment: I think [databinding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f0f3cd6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) is what you´re looking for. This enables you to connect each Input field to a property in the model. Using two way binding (which is default for JSONModel) every change is automatically replicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for one of the key features in UI5: `Data binding` of data values from a `Data Model` to a `View Control`.
You can find information about Databinding in the [UI5 Developer Guide.](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/ec699e0817fb46a0817b0fa276a249f8.html)